# React change specific element in an array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

so i have an array of objects like so

[image]

Currently i'm looping through the array and displaying all the item.clock minutes. Now on click i want to change the display to item.activeTeamAbbr but just for that specific element, currently it is updating every element of the array. Just wondering what the best way to go about this would be, presumably to use a for loop? I'll add the code below, any help is much appreciated.

```
class Bets extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items : [],
      showVid: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://www.nfl.com/feeds-rs/bigPlayVideos/2018/REG/5.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({items : res.bigPlays}))
   }


   showVideo(item){
    this.setState({showVid: true})
   }

   displayInfo(){
    let item = this.state.items.map((item, key) =>
    <li key={item.id}><button onClick={()=> this.showVideo(item)}> . 
    {item.clockMinutes}</button></li>
   );

   let displayInfo = this.state.items.map((item, key) =>
   <li key={item.id}>{item.activeTeamAbbr}</li>
  );

   if(this.state.showVid === false){
      return item
   }
      else return displayInfo
   }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.displayInfo()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Bets;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a single `showVid` state variable for all your items, you could have one on every element in the array and toggle that when the button is clicked.

**Example**

```js
class Bets extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
    showVid: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://www.nfl.com/feeds-rs/bigPlayVideos/2018/REG/5.json")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ items: res.bigPlays }));
  }

  showVideo = (index) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const items = [...prevState.items];
      items[index] = {
        ...items[index],
        showVid: !items[index].showVid
      };
      return { items };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.showVid ? (
              item.activeTeamAbbr
            ) : (
              <button onClick={() => this.showVideo(index)}>
                {item.clockMinutes}
              </button>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Bets />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A for loop would do, but a map may be cleaner. You need to keep track of what item you want to show, and inside the map, you will conditionally render it in one way or another.

Let's do a walkthrough so I can explain every detail.

In your `showVideo(item)` method, you need to keep track of what item you want to display. Start by storing its id in the state:

```js
showVideo(item) {
  this.setState({ showVid: item.id });
}
```

Your `displayInfo()` method will return a list and for each item it will call another function that will decide what to render:

```js
displayInfo() {
  return this.state.items.map(item => (
    <li key={item.id}>
      {displayItem(item)}
    </li>
  ))
}
```

The new `displayItem(item)` function will ask another function if the current item is selected, and conditionally render one thing or another:

```js
const displayItem = item => {
  if (isSelected(item)) {
    return // render the activeTeamAbbr here
  }
  return // render the unselected state here, which is the button
}
```

The new `isSelected(item)` function will compare the item id against the id you stored in the state. It can be defined as follows:

```js
const isSelected = item => this.state.showVid === item.id
```

If you want to allow multiple items to be switched, instead of a single one, the `showVid` state variable would be an object storing the states of each item:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    items: [],
    showVid: {} // this should be an object to store multiple ids
  };
}

showVideo(item) {
  this.setState({ showVid: { ...this.state.showVid, [item.id]: true}})
}
```

And simply modify the `isSelected` function defined previously in order to support the new type of the `showVid` variable:

```js
const isSelected = item => this.state.showVid[item.id]
```